Merge columns into one single column using pandas
I'm trying to concatenate the string values of 3 different columns into one single column with the name "Address".
This is my data: Dataframe
I've tried this code:
def get_data(input_file, location_file, output_file):

  df1 = pd.read_excel(input_file, sheet_name="Destino")

  df2 = pd.read_excel(location_file)
  df2_filtered = df2[['TWLAD LGORT Depósito', 'ADRC POST_CODE1 Código postal da cidade', 'ADRC CITY1 Local', 'ADRC STREET Rua']]
  
  df = df1.merge(df2_filtered, left_on='PlanoDestino', right_on='TWLAD LGORT Depósito')
  df = df.drop(columns='TWLAD LGORT Depósito')

  df['Address'] = df['ADRC STREET Rua'] + ' ' + df['ADRC CITY1 Local'] + ' ' + df['ADRC POST_CODE1 Código postal da cidade']

But it's returning a not concatenated column: Dataframe with Address column
What do I need to do?
I need that the new column "Address" be like this example: "Rua das Pereiras Aveiro 3810-310"

It might be a problem that there are leading or trailing whitespaces in one or both of your data frames meaning they can't be matched up correctly.
To solve this, try removing whitespaces using the strip() function in your data frames like below before trying to join them together:
df['TWLAD LGORT Depósito'] = df['TWLAD LGORT Depósito'].str.strip()
df['ADRC POST_CODE1 Código postal da cidade'] = df['ADRC POST_CODE1 Código postal da cidade'].str.strip()
df['ADRC CITY1 Local'] = df['ADRC CITY1 Local'].str.strip()
df['ADRC STREET Rua'] = df['ADRC STREET Rua'].str.strip()

Then the line:
df['Address'] = df['ADRC STREET Rua'] + ' ' + df['ADRC CITY1 Local'] + ' ' + df['ADRC POST_CODE1 Código postal da cidade']

should give you the output you expect.
